# Dynamically updating v-combobox items list

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Is it possible somehow to update Vuetify `v-combobox`  items as the user is typing? I want to change the list of available items depending on what the users started typing, to create an address input with suggestions from a geolocation API.
This is what I tried: `@update:search-input='fetchAddresses'`
And in fetchAddresses: `this.items = newListOfItems`

However, while `@update:search-input` fires as expected, the combobox list will only be updated after losing focus. Can I somehow trigger it to be updated? (This may very well be an X/Y problem, so any hints about other approaches are welcome)

My current, ugly, hack is to force the whole combobox component to re-render with the current value set, and then refocus on it. (There is an activateMenu() method on the combobox that I could use to make sure the list reopened:

```js
this.$nextTick(() => {
  if (this.$refs.addressCombobox) {
    this.$refs.addressCombobox.focus()
    this.$refs.addressCombobox.activateMenu()
  }
})
```

I'm using Vue 2.

Comment: how you are using vuetify with vue3?

Comment: @ashwinbande I'm not, that was a typo.. :) thanks!

Comment: You can simply build your own select - by using `v-menu` (with nested `v-list`) and `v-text-field`. Then you can control the `v-list-item`s directly.

Comment: @IVOGELOV That might indeed be the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `no-filter` solved this problem

```
<v-combobox no-filter ... >
```